# UK Standard Visa - Monthly Savings

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Please bear with me on this one...
I have read somewhere that regardless of your savings for trip, the ECO also looks at your monthly spendings or how much you save per month out of your income. for example: if your salary 1000 $ and you save only 50 $ a month, even if you got savings enough for the trip, the visa will be rejected. This has raised concerns for me, in my case, my salary is about 1900 $ and I save 270 $ a month. I now have 4000 $ in savings. will my application in this case be at risk of rejection?

Sorry for the long question and Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There are no hidden rules, and no absolutes. Regarding amounts saved: the important point is that your proposed expenditure for the trip must be seen as reasonable given your financial circumstances. Please review the long and extensive answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). There's far more to a successful application than just money in the bank.

Comment: Reading the section on *Assessing an applicant’s personal circumstances* in https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf might be of interest to you, if you’ve not already seen it

Answer (score 2):

What UK immigration is trying to asses is whether you are at risk of being an illegal immigrant in UK. Finances can show many signs. Say, you are spending your entire life savings on a trip to UK, then its more than likely that you are not coming back.

In your case, other circumstances are not given. What's your purpose of visit? Where are you going to stay? How much money are you going to spend? Are you having strong ties to your home country, by having a family, properties, job etc. All these matters.

Have an assessment yourself and apply.

Comment: im travelling for tourisim. My employer have provided me with a no objection to travel letter. I do have family and car under my name that I pay installments for. so I have got ties in my country. I dont plan to spend all of my savings ofcourse. At most half of them. my worry is that my monthly spendings might appear too much to the ECO..

Comment: @AyaRS So you plan to spend 7 months worth of savings on a vacation, is that correct?

Comment: Having a car on instalments isn’t a particularly strong tie (you could easily keep paying from outside your home country); in addition to your job, *dependent* family ties would be likely to carry most weight. A good travel history is pretty essential too IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Beware of placing large lump sums into your bank account in an attempt to show that you have enough funds for the trip.  If the source cannot be verified then UKVI can rightly have concerns.

i.e. take this example - it may seem like a good idea for a friend to put 10000USD in your account so when you apply for the visa you can show there is more than enough money for the trip, simply to return it once he visa is issue.

UKVI will want to know where the money came from so they can be sure the money is yours and will be available for the trip.  So they will be happy to see your savings moving around between your own accounts, your employer paying your salary, perhaps even a lump sum bonus if it is obvious where it came from.  All of this can be backed up with further documents, payslips etc... letters from your employer confirming the bonus amounts for example.

However a lump sum arriving from an unknown source can lead to visa refusal as it calls into question whether or not you would genuinely have access to it.

See [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor) for the official rules for the visa issuance. 4.2 (e) is the important point.  And then [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-finance) for the specific rules on finances referred to.

Comment: @Aya RS For a more extensive assessment of the funds parking issue, and savings in general, take a look at [this question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab).